# How to handle summarizing the rates in Paginated report?

Tags: reporting-services, power-bi-report-server, powerbi-paginated-reports

I'm coming from Power BI background where-in I would have created a measure to solve this problem.

However there is no measure in the paginated report so need some help.

I'm using Power bi report server and a paginated report. I have following fields in the dataset:

Client, date, emp_count, emp_call

This contains 1 record per day per client. I want to show this in a matrix visual along with emp_call/emp_count value.

So I added emp_call/emp_count as a dataset column (called it rate), and inserted the matrix via wizard and the matrix shows client, date, emp_count, emp_calls, rate (formatted rate as percentage).

Now the daily values are correct but the aggregate percentage value at the client level is wrong (because it does a SUM by default). So I removed the SUM function from the expression and just kept it as rate [rather than SUM(rate)], and the result is still wrong. What is the correct way to handle such aggregations?

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to use

```
=SUM(Fields!emp_call.Value) / SUM(Fields!emp_count.Value)
```

If fact you could use the same expression in your detail rows and it should work fine, so there is no need to calculate and add the rate column to the dataset.

*One more thing, I would try to avoid using the Wizard as it's not very magical and try working from a blank report. When I started out, I used the Wizard but quickly ended up spending more time fixing things than the time it would have taken to do it from scratch.*

Comment: So start with blank report, and then add a matrix / table via wizard or not to use wizard at all? I'm still trying to get my head across the concept of header/detail/total and the advanced thing at the bottom

Comment: I'm not saying don't use the wizards just that I find it gets in the way in a lot of cases and it helps understand how reports work if you do it manually. Typically, I write my dataset queries first and add those in, then drop in tables/matrices etc that I need and drop the dataset fields onto them. If you drop these in the right place you can generate the row/column groupings automatically. There's lots of info you there, mainly because Power BI Paginated reports is essentially SSRS and 99% of the practices can be applied to both.

Comment: Take look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/understanding-groups-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver16 for example